# Request in test APIClient fails after authenticating twice

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest-django

After upgrading to django 5, our test suite started showing odd behavior. We are using [DRF's APIClient](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient) and authentication does not work as expected anymore. Certain API requests return `rest_framework.exceptions.NotAuthenticated` with status code 403 (by the way, if someone could explain why this status is 403 and not 401, I'd appreciate).

This is seemingly arbitrary. Among 2 requests to views which are implemented identically in terms of user permissions etc, one returns 403 **during testing only**. Executing the same calls in Postman does not reproduce the error.
Thus, some of the exact same test cases which used to pass under django 4 do not pass anymore under django 5 due to above error. I did not manage to reproduce these cases in a minimal example.

What I did reproduce however, is the following:

```
client.force_authenticate(user)
client.get(url)  # the user does not have permissions. response is 403, as expected
client.force_authenticate(None)  # "log out"
user.user_permissions.add(permission)
client.force_authenticate(user)
response = client.get(url)  # the now has permissions. response 200 is expected
assert response.status_code == 200  # response status is 403
```

Package versions are

```
django==5.0.3
djangorestframework==3.15.0
pytest==7.4.3
pytest-django==4.7.0
```

I have made a [minimal project](https://github.com/konnerthg/minimal-django5-drf-test-client-cant-authenticate-twice) where this can be observed.

As far as I managed to test it, this unexpected behavior occurs in both django 4 and 5.
Am I using the test client incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is described in the docs:

> The ModelBackend caches permissions on the user object after the first
> time they need to be fetched for a permissions check. This is
> typically fine for the request-response cycle since permissions aren’t
> typically checked immediately after they are added (in the admin, for
> example). If you are adding permissions and checking them immediately
> afterward, in a test or view for example, the easiest solution is to
> re-fetch the user from the database.
>
> [Permissions caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#permission-caching)

The solution:

```
client.force_authenticate(user=user)
client.get("/test/")
client.force_authenticate(user=None)

user.user_permissions.add(permission)
# Getting a new user instance. 
# user.refresh_from_db() does not clear cache
user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user.id)

client.force_authenticate(user=user)
response = client.get("/test/")

assert response.status_code == 200
```

Concerning the `response.status_code` returned for unauthenticated request there is this relevant bit of information in DRF docs:

> When an unauthenticated request is denied permission there are two
> different error codes that may be appropriate.
>
> HTTP 401 Unauthorized
>
> HTTP 403 Permission Denied
>
> HTTP 401 responses must always include a WWW-Authenticate header, that instructs the
> client how to authenticate. HTTP 403 responses do not include the
> WWW-Authenticate header.
>
> The kind of response that will be used depends on the authentication
> scheme. Although multiple authentication schemes may be in use, only
> one scheme may be used to determine the type of response. The first
> authentication class set on the view is used when determining the type
> of response.

If DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES are not specified in settings, the default ones are used:

```
[
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
]
```

After disabling SessionAuthentication class (or changing the order of authentication classes, BasicAuthentication first), 401 responses are returning for unauthenticated requests.